# How can I use rest_framework.authtoken without create table authtoken_token in Django

Tags: python, django

When I added `rest_framework.authtoken` and used `Token.objects.get_or_create(user = user)` for check auth call API, django request must create table `authtoken_token` in DB, but customer don't want add new table in DB.

So, have any way resolve it?

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: where is the code ? feed us some code :)

Comment: try JWT JSON Web Token

Comment: Thanks @JibinMathews :D

Comment: Thanks @Ahtisham, I think I will research https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework needs to create the table to store the access tokens if you're using the built in token authentication.

As mentioned in the comments, there are other options, including JWT. The library recommended by the DRF documentation is this one:

https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt